# ¿Cómo extraigo una sola fecha y cantidad de la tabla?

Tags: mysql, sql

Bajo una consulta MySQL:

```
SELECT yearweek(fecha) as Año_Semana, SUM(is_e0_partespequenas) 
FROM inmision_saco 
group by 1;
```

me muestra la siguiente información:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo extraer solo una fila de una semana? En este caso de `2019-13` y la cantidad sumada solamente...

Intento hacer mi consulta de la siguiente manera; sí me da la semana que ocupo, pero me hace la suma total de todas las cantidades:

```
SELECT yearweek('2022-04-01') as Año_Semana, SUM(is_e0_partespequenas)  
FROM inmision_saco 
group by 1;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué necesito añadir o modificar para solo extraer la información que necesito solo de la primer fila, como se muestra en la primera imagen?

Comment: Que quieres decir con "extraer solo una fila de una semana"?

Comment: Hola Hugo, te recomiendo realizar el [tour] para aprender sobre como funciona el sitio y de paso ganar tu segunda medalla.

Answer (score 1):

> Como puedo extraer solo una fila de una semana ? en este caso de 2019-13 y la cantidad sumada solamente...

Tendrías indicar que queres obtener los registros donde `yearweek(fecha) = '201913'`

#### Ejemplo:

```sql
SELECT 
    YEARWEEK(fecha) as Año_Semana,
    SUM(is_e0_partespequenas) 
FROM inmision_saco 
WHERE YEARWEEK(fecha) = '201913'
GROUP BY 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Dado que quieres una sumatoria total para una sola semana, no hace falta agrupar, sino filtrar la consulta.

Puedes lograrlo con una sentencia como esta:

```
SELECT SUM(is_e0_partespequenas) 
  FROM inmision_saco 
 where yearweek(fecha) = '201913';
```

Esto te devolverá una única fila con un único campo que contiene el total para la semana 201913.